# PHP code not retrieving data from database?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I use the VirtueMart component on my site.

I have this piece of code running on Joomla 3.6:

```
<?php 
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with 
//"custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('customfield_value', 
'virtuemart_product_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id') . ' LIKE '. $db-
>quote('3'). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id') . 'LIKE ' . 
$db->quote($product->virtuemart_product_id));

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more 
options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo ($results); 
?>
```

However, for some reason, it's not loading the data. I just get a blank page. On my localhost it's working fine, yet on my live site it's not loading at all.

Any reason why this could be? It's using the same database (phpmyadmin).

Hosting issue possibly?

I don't know. I've tested everything offline for a week and it all went swimmingly and then this happens. I don't see ANY errors in the console, so I don't know what could be wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try debugging it line by line

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Very weird that it's not working. Think it's something with the server.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when you transfer your database to the server. because some of the servers have a different configuration for the database server like it may be running a database server on localhost:8080. so first check your DB config file for configuration.if you still found the same problem then I will suggest enabling PHP error reporting to 1 so that you can see what actually causing this problem.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was the server and database possibly. Also I'm using godaddy as a host and they're not really good at all. Thinking of moving.

Comment: Goddady Always sucks it happened to me also lot of time too  :))